# Is there any calculator where you can put a set amount of money in and track the actual returns of the S&P 500 between any dates provided?

Tags: rate-of-return, growth

I want to find a calculator where between any two dates provided, the return on a given amount of money is calculated for the actual returns of the S&P 500 between those dates.

Answer (score 2):

[MoneyChimp](http://www.moneychimp.com/features/market_cagr.htm) is great for this. It only offers full year returns, but it compounds the results correctly, including dividends. 
For mid year results, just adjust a bit based on the data you can find from Google or Yahoo to add some return (or loss) for the months.

Answer (score -1):

Well i dont know of any calculator but you can do the following

1) Google [S&P 500](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXSP:.INX) chart

2) Find out whats the S&P index points (P1) on the first date

3) Find out whats the S&P index points (P2) on the second date

4) P1 - P2 = result

```
   returns in % = result / P1 * 100
```

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. Nice try, unfortunately, the S&P index does not reflect dividends. So Jan, 1980 at 114.16 to Dec 2013, 1848.36, looks like only a 1519% return, pretty awful compared to actual return of 4355% when you include dividends.